# ORMLite: is there a way to inform which reference the QueryBuilder should use for the join?

Tags: android, join, ormlite

I'm trying to execute a joined query on the following classes:

```
public class EquipmentCharacteristic {
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, uniqueCombo = true)
    private Equipment equipment;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, uniqueCombo = true)
    private Characteristic characteristic;

    ...
}

public class Characteristic {
    ...
}

public class Equipment {
    ...
}
```

QueryBuilder:

```
QueryBuilder<EquipmentCharacteristic, ?> daoEC = entityDAO.getDAO(
            EquipmentCharacteristic.class).queryBuilder();
daoEC.where().eq(EquipmentCharacteristic.EQUIPMENT + "_id", equipment.getId());

QueryBuilder<Characteristic, ?> daoCharacteristic = entityDAO.getDAO(
    Characteristic.class).queryBuilder();

return daoEC.join(daoCharacteristic)
    .selectRaw(
            "EquipmentCharacteristic." + EquipmentCharacteristic.ID, 
            "EquipmentCharacteristic." + EquipmentCharacteristic.EQUIPMENT + "_" + Equipment.ID, 
            "EquipmentCharacteristic." + EquipmentCharacteristic.POSSIBLE_VALUES, 
            "EquipmentCharacteristic." + EquipmentCharacteristic.CHARACTERISTIC + "_" + Characteristic.ID, 
            "EquipmentCharacteristic." + EquipmentCharacteristic.VALUE, 
            "Characteristic." + Characteristic.FIXED_VALUE, 
            "Characteristic." + Characteristic.UNIT, 
            "Characteristic." + Characteristic.CHARACTERISTIC)
    .queryRaw().closeableIterator();
```

The problem is that the created query joins with Equipment and not Characteristic:

```
SELECT 
    EquipmentCharacteristic.id, 
    EquipmentCharacteristic.equipment_id, 
    EquipmentCharacteristic.possibleValues, 
    EquipmentCharacteristic.characteristic_id, 
    EquipmentCharacteristic.value, 
    Characteristic.fixedValue, 
    Characteristic.unit, 
    Characteristic.characteristic 
FROM `EquipmentCharacteristic` INNER JOIN `Characteristic` ON `EquipmentCharacteristic`.`equipment_id` = `Characteristic`.`id`
```

**If I put the Characteristic reference in EquipmentCharacteristic before Equipment, the problem doesn't occur.**

```
public class EquipmentCharacteristic {
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, uniqueCombo = true)
    private Characteristic characteristic;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, uniqueCombo = true)
    private Equipment equipment;

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to inform which table (class) the QueryBuilder should use for the join?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow.  This looks like a bug in ORMLite.  At the very least it should verify that the DAO method entity matches the field.

Comment: Yeah I would.  Either in the SourceForge or on github.  http://ormlite.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the created query joins with Equipment and not Characteristic:

I'm sorry but I've not been able to reproduce this.  I've added the following tests to trunk.  If you can figure out why my tests work but you code fails, that would be very helpful.

> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/78223c682aa0d7063c095afc0e26b466aeb618af

Not much of an answer unfortunately.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this with a test soon. For now, thanks for the support, Gray.